# How Do I Hide/Remove Part Of A Column With Java or jQuery, I have no access to HTML and suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

There are 2 sections stacked on top of each other in "grid_8". I need to remove the top section which includes STATS, Statistics, Graph..ect (Plus I don't have any access to change the HTML) I need a JS code that will remove the top section in the column. I have highlighted all the code that needs to be removed/hid in JS. Please help!

Recap:
*RIGHT COLUMN > STATS > html5 graph > end html5 graph* = **REMOVE OR HIDE**
*FEATURED OFFERS* = **KEEP WITH JS**

-----DOCUMENTS---CSS-&-JS-------
media.go2app.org/assets/css/base.css?new=1
media.go2app.org/assets/css/default.css?new=1
media.go2app.org/assets/css/print.css
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/graph/jquery.js
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/jquery/jquery.metadata-3620.min.js
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/jquery/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/jquery/jquery.base64.js
media.go2app.org/assets/shared/js/jquery/jquery.thickbox.min.js
media.go2app.org/assets/css/thickbox.css
media.go2app.org/assets/js/global.js?new=1
media.go2app.org/assets/js/jquery-fluid16.js
media.go2app.org/assets/js/base.js?new=1
media.go2app.org/assets/js/superfish.js
media.go2app.org/assets/css/style7.css?new=1
media.go2app.org/assets/js/excanvas.js
media.go2app.org/assets/css/ie6.css
media.go2app.org/assets/css/ie.css

---------------------------------------CODE--REMOVE BELOW---------------------------------

```
<!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
<div class="grid_8">
    <!-- STATS -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQueryBackup = jQuery;
        jQuery = jqForGraph;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqChart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

    <div class="panel">
        <div class="head">
            <h3>Statistics</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="body">

            <div class="graph">
                <div class="snapDateRange">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                <form name="date_range_form" method="post" action="/snapshot"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="" id="" />            
                        <div class="date-icon"></div>

                        <label>View Stats for</label>


            <select name="data[DateRange][preset_date_range]" id="DateRangePreset">
<option value="other"></option>
<option value="today" selected="selected">Today</option>

<option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
<option value="last_seven_days">Last 7 Days</option>
<option value="this_month">This Month - December</option>
<option value="last_month">Last Month - November</option>
<option value="last_six_months">Last Six Months</option>
<option value="all_time">All Time</option>
</select>           
            <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="" id="TokenFields948847344" /></form>                       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                $("#DateRangePreset").change(function(){ this.form.submit(); });
            </script>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="grapherror"></div>
                    <div id="earningsGraph" style="min-width: 400px;clear: both;height: 300px"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>                           
                </div>
                <div style="height:350; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div id="volumeGraph" style="min-width: 400px;clear: both;height: 300px"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>                           
                </div>


                                    <!-- html5 graph -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[

var chart1, chart2;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // define the options
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'earningsGraph',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Earnings',
            style: {
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23'],
            lineColor: '#000000',
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0) + '';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false,
            gridLineColor: '#000000'
        }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                   return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0) + '';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 5,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b style="color:#333;font-weight:bold;">'+ this.x +'</b>';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + 
                        point.series.name +'</span> : <b>$'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2) +'<b>';
                });

                return s;
            },
            style: {
                'line-height': '120%' /*ie9 fix*/
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Payout',
            data: [0.00000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        }]
    });

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'volumeGraph',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Volumes',
            style: {
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23'],
            lineColor: '#000000',
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: 'Conversions',
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false,
            gridLineColor: '#000000'
        }, { // right y axis
            gridLineWidth: 0,           
            title: {
                text: 'Clicks',
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                   return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false,
            opposite: true
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 5,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<span style="color:#333;font-weight:bold;">'+ this.x +'</span>';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + 
                        point.series.name +'</span> : <strong>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0) +'</strong>';
                });

                return s;
            },
            style: {
                'line-height': '120%' /*ie9 fix*/
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Conversions',
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        }, {
            name: 'Clicks',
            data: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
jQuery = jQueryBackup;
                    //]]>
                    </script>
                    <!-- end html5 graph -->    

                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <p>Stats are displayed in Eastern Time (America/New York).</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

---------------------------------------CODE--REMOVE ABOVE---------------------------------

```
<!-- FEATURED OFFERS -->

    <div class="panel">
    <div class="head">
        <h3>Featured Offers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                <div id="footer" class="grid_12">
                            <p>
                                                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: All code above is the entire column, I broke it up to show that the top code is what needs to be removed, but it all flows as one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the div element with the class "grid_8", and everything in it. With jQuery:

```
$(".grid_8").remove();
```

Note though that selecting by class will also remove any other elements with that same class.

If you wanted to hide it rather than remove you could try this:

```
$(".grid_8").hide();
```

For more information read the [jQuery doco for `.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

**EDIT:** OK, so you don't really want to remove the .grid_8 div. To remove the first .panel div inside the .grid_8 one, _assuming there are no other .grid_8 elements on the page_, try the following:

```
$(".grid_8 .panel").first().remove();
// OR
$(".grid_8 .panel:first").remove();
```

If there are multiple .grid_8 elements then you can specify the one you want by supplying a zero-based index. E.g., to remove the first .panel from the sixth .grid_8:

```
$(".grid_8:eq(5) .panel:first").remove();
```

(Note that the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector is equivalent to [`:eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).)

Comment: yes, but I want to keep "Featured Offers" which is inside .grid_8. So that won't work. It will remove everything.

Comment: <!-- FEATURED OFFERS -->

    <div class="panel">
    <div class="head">
        <h3>Featured Offers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                                                <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: I want to keep FEATURED OFFERS, all the above.

Comment: If you don't really want to remove the .grid_8 div then why on earth did you include it in the section you've highlighted for removal? I'm not a mindreader... Perhaps what you really want is to remove the .panel div? If so then I'm sure you can figure out from my answer above what you need to do...but again without any ids to select on all you can do is select by class which will remove any other elements with the same class. There are ways to remove the first of a class, or the nth, but I can't guess which of those would apply to your situation when there could be other .grid_8 elements.

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot add comments yet.)

Can you provide the whole html source of that page.

```
$(".grid_8 .panel:first").remove();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, One more question. Is there a JS code that I can use to move the first panel to below the second panel?

Comment: Basically, changing their order, second panel first (top) and first panel second (bottom)?

Comment: See jQuery's .before(): $(".grid_8 .panel:eq(3)").before('.grid_8 .panel:eq(2)'); [note: ":eq(index)" index is the order. Starts at 0]